# Terraform Error while Passing output variable from one module to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using two modules vpc and lb and passing an output varibale in vcp module to lb module as below in the code. But I am getting following error -

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 35, in module "lb":
  35:   vpc-id = module.vpc.vpc-id

This value does not have any attributes.
```

Here is code -
main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
  region =var.region      
}
# Include modules
module "vpc" {
  count = var.create_default_vpc ? 1:0
  source = "./modules/vpc"
  region = var.region
  zones = var.zones
}

module "lb" {
  source  = "./modules/lb"
  image = var.image
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  vpc-id = module.vpc.vpc-id
}
```

./modules/vpc/vpc.tf

```
resource "aws_vpc" "xcloud-vpc" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    Name = "xcloud-vpc"
  }
}
```

./modules/vpc/vpc-output.tf

```
output "vpc-id" {
  value = aws_vpc.xcloud-vpc.id
}
```

./modules/lb/lb.tf

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_http" {
  name        = "xcloud-sg-allow-http"
  description = "Allow HTTP & ICMP inbound connections"
  vpc_id = var.vpc-id
  # vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc-id
  <some more ingress, egress code>
```

./modules/lb/lb-vars.tf

```
variable image {}
variable instance_type {}
variable vpc-id{}
```

Though I am passing vpc-id = module.vpc.vpc-id while including "lb" module in the main.tf , the above error is given for this line of code. Any pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you also define variable "vpc-id" in your lb module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `count` in your `module`, you should refer to individual instances of the module, even if you have only one. So in your case, it would be:

```
vpc_id = module.vpc[0].vpc-id
```